# How do I put new accounts into html file using a create account page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to save the account information like the username and password that are being collected from the createaccount.html file so they can be used in the login.html page. I am new to the html css and javascript scene and know no PHP. If it has to be PHP please explain how I would enter it into this. Below are both the createaccount.html file and the login.html file.

```
createaccount.html
```

```js
 function check(form){
   if(form.psw.value == form.repsw.value && form.repsw.value == form.psw.value){
     alert('Passwords Match')
   } else {
      alert('Passwords do not match')
   }
 }
```

```css
 h1 {
   text-align: center;
 }
            
 .passwordcheck{
    color: white;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
  <head>
    <title> Create a Account </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h6> All questions with a * are required</h6>
    <h1> Create an Account </h1>
    <form>
      <div align='center'>
        Username <input class='username' type='text' placeholder='Username' required>*<br>
        Password <input class='password' type='password' name='psw' placeholder='Password' required>*<br>
        Retype Password <input class='password' type='password' name='repsw' placeholder='Retype Password' required>*
        <input type='button' onclick='check(this.form)' class='passwordcheck' value='Check Password'><br>
        Email <input class='email' type='text' placeholder='johndoe476@gmail.com' required>*<br>
        Phone Number <input class='number' type='text' placeholder='815-555-5035'><br>
        Gender *<br>
        <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Male'> Male<br>
        <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Female'> Female<br>
        <input type='submit' value='Create Account'>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

```
login.html
```

```js
function check(form){
  if (form.username.value == 'Xander2355' && form.psw.value == 'Blackops3') {
    window.open('practicelog.html')
  } else {
    alert('This username or password is incorrect');
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
            
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
            
.username{
  border-color: #333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
            
.password{
  border-color: #333;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Login </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1> Login </h1>
      <div align='center'>
    <form>
      <input class='username' type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' required>
      <br>
      <input class='password' type='password' name='psw' placeholder='Password' required>
      <br>
      <input type='button' onclick='check(this.form)' value='Login'>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div align='right'>
    <a onclick='window.location.href = "createaccount.html";' class='button'> Create Account</a>
  </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: (I hope `Blackops3` isn't a real password you use, but if so you should absolutely change it now that you've posted it to SO.com)

Comment: You really don't want to persist account data in an HTML file.

Comment: Checking login credentials in *client-side* JavaScript is pointless.

Comment: You don't.  Store accounts server-side in a database, not in an HTML file.

Comment: You will want to have something on a web server to store user account information, either in a database or protected file. You can access that information from your database using server-side technology, like PHP, Ruby on Rails, Node.js, ASP.NET, etc. There are lots of security concerns involved here. It's recommend you use a pre-built user management system to manage user accounts and passwords instead of re-inventing the wheel. It's beyond a single question to write a whole user management solution out.

Comment: As mentioned, using a database is one of the more common ways to persist data for your web application. Check out [What are databases?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls_LzOZ7x0c)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this just for learning purpose then use `localStorage` to store account data. Each account created can be saved as a name-value pair. Learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

If you are doing this for production, use backend server that provides API to store, retrieve, update, delete and validate user accounts with a database to persist data permanently. Yes, use PHP and MySQL, to begin with. Find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)